# Get JSON keys to another object with different values

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, key

```
// data => JSON
Object.keys(data)
```

After I put keys of the JSON object into an array, I want to make another object with those keys and null values.

E.g. plain JSON:

```
{
    "a": "lorem",
    "b": "ipsum",
    "c": 
    {
        "info":
        {
            "1": "2",
            "3": "4"
        },
        "elephant": "bar"
    },
    "d":
    {
        "monkeys": "foo",
        "elephant": "bar:
    }
}
```

[I don't know the keys at runtime] I want to have this:

```
{
    "a": null,
    "b": null,
    "c": null,
    "d": null
}
```

How do i approach that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` on `Object.keys()` and return new object.

```js
var obj = {"a":"lorem","b":"ipsum","c":{"info":{"1":"2","3":"4"},"elephant":"bar"},"d":{"monkeys":"foo","elephant":"bar"}}

var r = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, e) {
  return r[e] = null, r
}, {})

console.log(r)
```